# Points Per Minute (Basketball)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am dividing PPG (points per game) by MIN (minutes played) to get PPM (Points Per Minute), and want to weight this ratio on GP (number of games played). How do I weight PPM on GP?

Please be specific in your answer.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by weighting PPM by games played.  Are you trying to compare different players?  What is wrong with multiplying PPM by games played?  I'm not sure what that tells you.

Comment: Can you give us a little more on what you wish to achieve?

Comment: For example, a player scores 30 but only played in 10 games versus a player that scores 10 and played in 30 games. I'm trying to weight their performances.